# 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppLink.h' file not found

Tags: swift, swift4.2

I've encountered following error message after upgraded my project swift version.

> 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppLink.h' file not found

```
pod => 1.6.0.beta.2

Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.39.1)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.39.1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use it like this in your podfile

> pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', :git =>
>   'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-objc-sdk.git', :branch =>
>   'master'

then run pod install, it's a bug on facebook SDK.